# Use of "while" instead of "for" in C

Tags: c, while-loop

Hello I'm new to programming, and would want to return an array in a "while" condition (not use "for"), any tips to make my program working please? Thanks

```
int numberPlayer=0;
    int *listPlayers= NULL;
    int i;

    printf("How many players");
    scanf("%d",&numberPlayer);

    listPlayers= malloc(sizeof(int) * numberPlayer);

    if (listPlayers==NULL){
        exit(1);
    }

    i=0;
    while(i<numberPlayer){
         printf("Joueur n° %d", i*3);
         listPlayers[i]= i*3;
         i++;

    }

    while(i<numberPlayer){
        printf("%d", listPlayers[i]); 
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Reset `i` before the 2nd `while` loop.

Comment: When using `while` sometimes the intention is to not reset the iterator.  The bug might be an intentional feature.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should learn how to use function. return array pointer is available for function not for commands like while, for.
you can check this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_return_arrays_from_function.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a perfect illustration of the superiority of the `for` loop over the `while` loop. It is a shame some schools insist on students using only `while` loops (42, Epita, Epitech...)

You forgot to initialize `i = 0` before the second `while` loop. A classical `for` loop combines initialization, test and increment in the `for` clauses, making it easy to read and verify.

For proper output, you should use a separator between the numbers and output a newline.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int numberPlayers = 0;
    int *listPlayers = NULL;
    int i;

    printf("How many players? ");
    if (scanf("%d", &numberPlayers) != 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    listPlayers = malloc(sizeof(int) * numberPlayers);
    if (listPlayers == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    i = 0;
    while (i < numberPlayers) {
         printf("Joueur n° %d? ", i * 3);
         if (scanf("%d", &listPlayers[i]) != 1)
             return 1;
         i++;
    }

    printf("Liste des joueurs: ");
    i = 0;
    while (i < numberPlayers) {
        printf("[%d]", numberPlayers[i]); 
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(listPlayers);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I saw this after posting too, but when I initialize i=0, it still don't work properly...

Comment: @Kytana You need to be way more specific than _don't work properly_.

Comment: I would like the array to return [X][X][X]...[X] in printf("%d", listPlayers[i]) , but nothing appear in the console

Comment: @Kytana you should use `fflush(stdout)` after the loop if you are not using endlines `\n` in your `printf` because `stdout` is buffered.

Comment: @AbrahamLe: that may help on some systems... streams are supposed to be flushed automatically upon exit though.